# BeautifulSoup not extracting all pages

Tags: python

I'm trying to practice some web scraping for a school project, but can't figure out why my script isn't pulling all the listings for a particular region? Would appreciate any help! I've been trying to figure out for hours!

(For simplicity, I'm just sharing one small sub-section of a page i'm trying to scrape. i'm hoping once I can figure out what's wrong here, I can apply it to other regions)

(You might need to create an account to login to see prices, before scraping)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://condos.ca')

def get_page(page):
    url= f'https://condos.ca/toronto/condos-for-sale size_range=300%2C999999999&property_type=Condo%20Apt%2CComm%20Element%20Condo%2CLeasehold%20Condo&mode=Sold&end_date_unix=exact%2C2011&sublocality_id=22&page={page}'
    driver.get(url) 
    page_source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
       return soup

prices=[]
location=[]

for page in range(5):
    soup = get_page(page)
    for tag in soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'styles___AskingPrice-sc-54qk44-4 styles___ClosePrice-sc-54qk44-5 dHPUdq hwkkXU'):
    prices.append(tag.get_text())

for tag in soup.find_all('address',class_ = 'styles___Address-sc-54qk44-13 gTwVlm'):
    location.append(tag.get_text())
```

For some reason, i'm only getting an output with 48 records, when it should be around 146.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the content you’re after is added to the DOM using JavaScript; BeautifulSoup has no support for evaluating the results of JavaScript calls by design.

Comment: Thanks! is there a better way I could do this instead? Or there's no way to use BeautifulSoup for this?

Comment: Selenium supports client rendering with javascript though. im wondering if its b/c you dont wait for the page to load before extracting the page source